# Requirement that $c_1$ vanish for a complete intersection in weighted complex projective space

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

What is the constraint for $c_{1}(M)$ to vanish if $M$ is defined to be a complete intersection of $k$ hypersurfaces each defined by polynomials in $\Bbb CP^{m}_{a_{0}...a_{n}}$?

Comment: you can cf this paper:    https://cds.cern.ch/record/178648/files/198706385.pdf

Comment: As far as I can tell this paper doesn't deal with complete intersections in weighted projective space. Is this case different than the constraint of c1(M) vanishing for complete intersections in standard complex projective spaces?